# Increasing call count quota in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, rate-limiting

I have an app set up in Facebook. However I encounter  a problem when I reach the FB rate limit very quickly. A quick search shows that the rate limit in FB is determined by how many active users an app has, however there is no specification in FB on when a user is considered active.

I've tried many various games with my own FB account, and sometimes the rate limit is indeed raised (I notice this because the percentage of rate limit used in the FB api dashboard is lowered by exactly half). But it is extremely hard to understand what specifically FB wants.

Has anyone managed to understand this?
TY

Comment: They are talking about the _"the number of unique daily active users"_ an app has, and IMHO the only way to interpret this that makes sense, is that it means, did you make an API call using an access token for that user today? If so, then they have been "active" in your app today.